# Как определить на какой странице пользователь

Tags: html, css

Есть 3 вкладки: главная, продукция и обратная связь. Нужно менять цвет фона той вкладки на которой сейчас пользователь. Как это сделать?

Comment: А как меняются вкладки: с перезагрузкой или без? Самый простой способ - добавить класс `.active` и дописать соответствующий стиль

Comment: Предоставьте, пожалуйста, [mcve]

Comment: С перезагрузкой. В вопросе не точно выразился, это страницы, а не вкладки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавить класс `.active` ко вкладке, соответствующей каждой странице, и дописать стиль:

```css
.active {
  /*здесь ваш стиль*/
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class='active'><a href='#'>Активная вкладка</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Неактивная вкладка</a></li>
</ul>
```